# Can I use two tm struct from time.h in the same file?

Tags: c, struct, time.h

I'm trying to do a book borrowing system witch can tell the user the day that they have to return the book. Because I have to use the data to check if the borrowing times are exceeding limit or not. I try to use two tm structures.

```
struct tm *Olddate;
struct tm *Newdate;
```

I added days to one of the structure like this

```
Newdate->tm_mday += 7;
```

When I tried to print out the two different struct, the output are somehow the same.

```
printf("Current local time and date: %s", asctime(Olddate));
printf("Current new time and date: %s", asctime(Newdate));
```

Output:

```
Current local time and date: Tue May 17 21:37:16 2022
New time and date: Tue May 17 21:37:16 2022
```

Minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main () {
    time_t rawtime;

    struct tm *Olddate;
    struct tm *Newdate;

    time( &rawtime );

    Olddate = localtime(&rawtime);
    Newdate = localtime(&rawtime);
    
    Newdate->tm_mday += 7;

    printf("Current local time and date: %s", asctime(Olddate));
    printf("New time and date: %s", asctime(Newdate));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: I edited the post for the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple `tm` structs.  What you can't have is multiple *pointers* to `tm` structs given to you by the `localtime` function.  If you print out `Olddate` and `Newdate` using `%p`, youll find that they're the same pointer, because `localtime` has only one `tm` struct at its disposal to return a pointer to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `localtime` function returns a pointer to static data, so the contents of that data can be overwritten an subsequent calls.

You should instead use `localtime_r` which accepts the address of a `struct tm` to populate.

```
time_t rawtime;

struct tm Olddate;
struct tm Newdate;

time( &rawtime );

localtime_r(&rawtime, &Olddate);
localtime_r(&rawtime, &Newdate);

Newdate.tm_mday += 7;

printf("Current local time and date: %s", asctime(&Olddate));
printf("New time and date: %s", asctime(&Newdate));
```

If you're using MSVC, use `localtime_s` instead.

```
localtime_s(&Olddate, &rawtime);
localtime_s(&Newdate, &rawtime);
```

Comment: This is true, and the correct answer, but it should be noted that you can always simply _copy_ the static data to a local variable as well. In a single-threaded program it has the same effect.

Comment: @witeseb Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: I tried running the given code on the online compiler and it works perfectly fine. but when I tried running on my visual studio code. I got a problem says "undefined reference to `localtime_r' "

Comment: @witeseb In that case, use `localtime_s` with the same parameters.

Comment: Still got the same problem. Both of them are somehow undefined?

Comment: @witeseb Actually, `localtime_s` has the parameters switched.

Comment: It's weird when I typed in localtime_r or localtime_s the floating tooltips shows that those function are just int localtime_r/s within the file I'm writing in, not from the time.h like a normal localtime.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244644/discussion-between-witeseb-and-dbush).